# Java generic type erasure: runtime type check on the field

Tags: java

I'm studying the Java Tutorials on Generics and playing with the example on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html in my own way.

Two classes:

```
public class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    public Node(T data) { 
        this.data = data; 
    }
    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class MyNode extends Node<Integer> {
    public MyNode(Integer data) { 
        super(data); 
    }
    public void setData(Integer data) {
        super.setData(data);
    }
}
```

Due to type erasure, following code will compile:

```
MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);  // 1
Node n = mn;                // 2
n.setData("Hello");         // 3
```

because line 3 is actually calling the type erased method Node.setData(Object). But a runtime `ClassCastException` will be thrown.

Here is my experiment: I printed out the type of the field `data`. It was `Object` in both Node and MyNode.

Here are my questions:

1. Node has an `Object` type with no surprise due to type erasure. But how come MyNode also has an `Object` type for "data"?
2. If MyNode's "data" has an `Object` type, how does the runtime type checking work? (The `ClassCastException` exception...) It seems to me the data type in MyNode has also been erased (my puzzle #1).

Java version: HotSpot 1.8.0_05-b13

Comment: Why do you overwrite the `setData` method. Since you inherit it, you don't need to reimplement it.

Comment: The override is exactly the point of the test. It illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I printed out the type of the field data

What you probably got printed out is a type for refence named "data". It is indeed set to `Object`.

> But how come MyNode also has an Object type for "data"?

Not sure which data you're talking about. Local variable `data`'s reference type is going to be `Integer` while attribute reference type is `Object`

> If MyNode's "data" has an Object type, how does the runtime type checking work? (The ClassCastException exception...) It seems to me the data type in MyNode has also been erased (my puzzle #1).

When you do this:

```
public void setData(Integer data) {
        super.setData(data);
}
```

Java compiler just turns it into this:

```
public void setData(Object arg) {
   Integer data = (Integer) arg;
    //Now you can use "data" refenrence with proper type
   super.setData(data);
}
```

This is where the ClassCastException is coming from.

Comment: That's a good point. The reference type doesn't mean anything here because the compiler rewrites `setData(Object)`. I have run a `javap -c` to confirm it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with `Generics` or`Type Erasure`.

You are telling the compiler `Node n` and not providing any type, so it will take anything.

This is no different than downcasting a `ArrayList<String>` down to `List` and complaining that it will take *anything*.

```
final List los = new ArrayList<String>();
los.add(new Date());
los.add(1);
```

This is well defined and expected behavior, it is doing what you are telling it to do.

#### What do you expect it to do other than exactly what you are telling it to do?

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I'm not surprised by the type erasure at all. I'm actually creating the problem for my experiment. I'm asking about the runtime type check. Please see the other answer.

Comment: **this has nothing to do with erasure and everything to do with the fact that there is no type information on `Node n`, there is nothing ot "erase" it is `Object` if nothing else is presented**

Comment: Please check the question post and the selected answer again. The question has nothing to do with `Node`.